# No hay respuesta de AJAX en aspx

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, aspx

Tengo un metodo en el codeBehind de un webForm en el que redirijo una consulta AJAX

```
[WebMethod]
public string buscarUser(string name, string pass)
{
     SqlDataReader rd;
     string resp = "CASA;
     return resp;
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on('click', '.loginBtn', function () {
        var datos = [];
        datos[0] = $("#tbUser").val();
        datos[1] = $("#tbPass").val();
        var datos={name: datos[0], pass: datos[1]};
        $.ajax({
            url: "Login.aspx/buscarUser",
            method: "POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(datos) ,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                alert(respuesta);

            }
        });
    })
```

La cuestion es que por mas que trate de mostrar el `alert(respuesta)`(CASA), siento que ni siquiera esta entrando al metodo, que es lo que falla en el codigo?

Comment: creo que el error debe estar aqui `"Login.aspx/buscarUser"` ya que direccionas a un archivo y luego  `/buscarUser` que es ?

Comment: @srJJ el nombre del metodo que esta en el primer ejemplo

Comment: no estoy seguro, pero creo que ajax no te ejecuta ese metodo asi, si no estoy errado, debes condicionar que si llegan los datos lo llamas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

El método debe ser declarado como publico y estático que son requisitos para los WebMethods.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string buscarUser(string name, string pass)
{
    return "CASA";
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on('click', '.loginBtn', function () {

    var datos = {
        name: $("#tbUser").val(),
        pass: $("#tbPass").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "Login.aspx/buscarUser",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (respuesta) {
            alert(respuesta.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: si agregas nadamas una explicación de que cambiaste será genial, para futuras consultas de otros que tengan la misma duda